# Trouble passing variable from returned JSON to a radio list filter for a basic search

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-component

First off, my apologies. I'm new to Vue and struggling a little bit. I have a basic search in which I'm passing a keyword to AWS CloudSearch and getting back JSON and displaying results. Basic keyword search works fine. I'm now trying to pass a data object called `studenttype` to a list of radios and filter based on that. Everything worked when I was working with stubbed out fake data in an external data file, but now that I'm fetching real data, it's not. I know I have to get the data from Axios, then post it as an option in TypeFilter.vue. I'm just not sure how to go about it. Thank you for your help.

Here's my App.vue file:

```
<template>
    <div class="app search">
        <!-- Search header -->
        <header id="searchHeader" class="search--header py-2 py-md-4">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <!-- Type filter -->
                    <TypeFilter v-model="studenttype" />

                    <!-- Location filter -->
                    <LocationFilter v-model="state" />

                    <!-- Search box -->
                    <SearchBox v-model="searchTerm"/>

                    <!-- More filters -->
                    <!--<div class="dropdown checkbox-dropdown mx-2">
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-white py-3 px-4 dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButtonFilters" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">More Filters</button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButtonFilters">
                        </div>
                    </div>-->

                    <!-- Search button -->
                    <button v-on:click="searchSubmit(searchTerm)" class="btn btn-lg btn-white ml-2 px-4 search-submit">Search</button>
                </div>

                <!-- Active filters (hidden for v0) -->
                <!--<div class="search--header--filters mt-3">
                    <span class="badge">Filter</span>
                    <span class="badge">Filter</span>
                    <span class="badge">Filter</span>
                </div>-->
            </div>
        </header>

        <!-- Main results -->
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Result count and show/sort -->
            <ResultCount v-model="page" :items="schools.length" :perPage="10"/>

            <!-- Results -->
            <SchoolList :schools="pageOfSchools"/>

            <!-- Pagination -->
            <Pagination v-model="page" :items="schools.length" :perPage="10"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import SchoolList from './SchoolList'
    import ResultCount from './ResultCount'
    import Pagination from './Pagination'
    import SearchBox from './SearchBox'
    import TypeFilter from "./TypeFilter";
    import LocationFilter from "./LocationFilter";
    import getArraySection from '../utilities/get-array-section'
    export default {
        name: 'app',
        components: {SchoolList, ResultCount, Pagination, SearchBox, TypeFilter, LocationFilter},
        data: () => ({
            searchTerm: '',
            studenttype: '',
            state: '',
            schools: [],
            page: 1,
        }),
        computed: {
            pageOfSchools: function () {
                return getArraySection(this.schools, this.page, 10)
            }
        },
        watch: {
            studenttype: function () {
                this.filterSchools()
            },
            state: function () {
                this.filterSchools()
            }
        },

        methods: {
            searchSubmit: function(terms) {
                axios.post("/search/college", {
                    "search": {
                        terms: terms.split(' ')
                    }
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        this.schools = response.data.hit
                        console.log(response.data)
                    })
            },

            filterSchools: function () {
                const searchTerm = this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()
                const studenttype = this.studenttype

                if (searchTerm) {
                    result = result.filter(school => {
                        return (
                            school.title.toLowerCase().search(searchTerm) >= 0 ||
                            school.location.toLowerCase().search(searchTerm) >= 0
                        )
                    })
                }

                if (studenttype) {
                    result = result.filter(school => school.studenttype.indexOf(studenttype) >= 0)
                }

                this.schools = result
                this.page = 1
            }
        },
        created: function () {
            this.filterSchools()
        }
    }
</script>
```

Here's my TypeFiler.vue file with the filter stuff:

```
<template>
  <div class="dropdown checkbox-dropdown d-none d-md-inline-block mr-2">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-white py-3 px-4 dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButtonType" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Choose Type</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButtonType">
      <template v-for="option in options">
        <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
          <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" :value="option" :name="name" v-model="selected">
          <label class="custom-control-label" v-if="option === ''">All</label>
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'checkbox-group',
    props: {
      value: {
        default: ''
      },
      options: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => ['', ...Object.keys(???)]
      },
      name: {
        type: String,
        default: 'type-filter'
      }
    },
    data: function() {
      return { selected: this.value }
    },
    watch: {
      selected: function(val) {
        this.$emit('input', val)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here's an example of the JSON I'm getting back:

```
{
    "found": 18,
    "start": "0",
    "cursor": "",
    "returned": 18,
    "hit": [{
        "name": "State Peter Pan Institute",
        "city": "New Burniceshire",
        "state": "Illinois",
        "areasofstudy": "Bachelor's",
        "degreetype": "BACHELORS",
        "studenttype": "UG",
        "schoolsnprograms": "state",
        "schoolsize": "1",
        "isCustomer": "0",
        "schoolUrl": "http://localhost/school/10/State Peter Pan Institute",
        "schoolLogo": 10
    }, {
        "name": "State Flatland University",
        "city": "New Ulices",
        "state": "Maryland",
        "areasofstudy": "Bachelor's",
        "degreetype": "BACHELORS",
        "studenttype": "UG",
        "schoolsnprograms": "state",
        "schoolsize": "1",
        "isCustomer": "0",
        "schoolUrl": "http://localhost/school/75/State Flatland University",
        "schoolLogo": 75
    }, {
        "name": "State Applewood Halls of Ivy",
        "city": "East Karimouth",
        "state": "West Virginia",
        "areasofstudy": "Bachelor's",
        "degreetype": "BACHELORS",
        "studenttype": "UG",
        "schoolsnprograms": "state",
        "schoolsize": "1",
        "isCustomer": "0",
        "schoolUrl": "http://localhost/school/89/State Applewood Halls of Ivy",
        "schoolLogo": 89
    }]
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what exactly do you wanna do?
Am I right you want to: get `schools` by `axios` - push `schools` to `TypeFilter` comnponent to get all available `studenttype` values - make a group of radiobuttons according to this values - filter `schools` by selected radio button in parent component?

Comment: Trying to pass all values of studenttype returned in the JSON in App.vue as radio options to the div class called "custom-control custom-radio" in TypeFiler.vue. EDIT: yep, you're spot on. I had it working when the JSON was in an external data file, as I just imported the JSON into TypeFilter.vue and referenced the data. However, now that it's not hardcoded data, I'm a bit lost.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's do it step-by-step:

At first we must get initial school list by `axios`:

```
searchSubmit: function(terms) {
  axios.post("/search/college", {
      "search": {
        terms: terms.split(' ')
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      this.schools = response.data.hit
      console.log(response.data)
    })
}
```

Then we should get all studenttypes available, I would do it as a computed function in root component:

```
computed: {
  allStudentTypes: function() {
    // checking if schools value is already available
    if (this.schools.hit) {
      let allStudentTypes = this.schools.hit.map(school => school.studenttype)
      // now we'll get unique values only
      let filteredStudentTypes = [...new Set(allStudentTypes)]
      return filteredStudentTypes
    } else {
      return []
    }
  }
}
```

Then we'll pass this value to `TypeFilter` component:

`<TypeFilter :options='allStudentTypes' v-model="studenttype" />`

`TypeFilter` component will do its job and pass `studenttype` variable to root component.

So now we're going to filter schools, I would advice you not to rewrite `schools` in data, let's do this in computed section instead:

```
computed: {
  allStudentTypes: ...,
  filteredSchools: function() {
    const searchTerm = this.searchTerm.toLowerCase()
    const studenttype = this.studenttype
    let result = this.schools

    if (searchTerm) {
      result = result.filter(school => {
        return (
          school.title.toLowerCase().search(searchTerm) >= 0 ||
          school.location.toLowerCase().search(searchTerm) >= 0
        )
      })
    }

    if (studenttype) {
      result = result.filter(school => school.studenttype.indexOf(studenttype) >= 0)
    }

    return result
  }
}
```

So now we could pass `filteredSchools` whenever we want.

And we also may remove `this.filterSchools()` from `created` and `watch` sections.

Comment: Thank you! So what would my final TypeFilter.vue file look like? I followed everything perfectly except for that part.

Comment: No. Do you freelance? I appreciate your in depth help but think I need further help.

Answer (score 0):

So you're going to want `studenttype` to be a `2-way data binding`. You can achieve this with `:sync` in Vue.

```
<TypeFilter :studenttype.sync="studenttype" />
```

Your `TypeFilter` component needs to accept `studenttype` as a property:

```
props: {
  studenttype: {
    type: String,
    default: null
  }
}
```

`TypeFilter` doesn't know about all the `student types` that it needs to be able to filter on. So you're going to need to pass those. One way to do this is with a computed property in the `parent component` (App.vue):

```
computed: {
  studentTypes: {
    get: function() {
      return this.schools.map(function(school) {
        return school.studenttype
      })
    }
  }
}
```

We can now supply that `computed getter` as the binding value to our `options` property in our `TypeFilter.vue` component.

```
<TypeFilter :studenttype.sync="studenttype" ::options="studentTypes"/>
```

Next, when the radio changes, you need to emit that value back to the parent. As you have a `watcher` setup on your input already, you only need to make one small change to support the `2-way` data binding:

```
this.$emit('udpate:studenttype', val)
```

When you click the radio, the parent (App.vue) value of `studenttype` will be updated to reflect the selection in the child (TypeFilter.vue). This binding will work between both components and there's no juggling needed.

Now that you have your `studenttype` and we have an array with a list of schools, we can use a computed getter to determine which schools should be visible (in App.vue):

```
visibleSchools: function() {
   switch(true) {
      case this.studenttype:
        return this.schools.filter(function(school) {
          return school.studenttype === this.studenttype
        })
        break
      default:
        return this.schools
   }
}
```

Finally pass `visibleSchools` to your `SchoolsList` component and that will show one of the following circumstances:

- Only schools matching the `studenttype`, if the `studenttype` is truthy, or
- All of the schools if there is not `studenttype` set.